# how can i add elments together inside the array in numpy?

Tags: numpy

here's the code:

```
print(array)
```

here's part of the outcomes:

```
array([[1.09080648e-07, 1.27947783e-07, 1.35521106e-07, 2.36965352e-03,
            1.76941751e-07, 6.02428392e-03, 1.93768765e-07],
            [1.17183374e-03, 1.54375957e-03, 4.94265019e-04, 1.72861062e-07,
            7.56083752e-04, 5.68696862e-03, 3.03002388e-04],...)
```

if i want to add elements in each row of the array, what should i do ?

i can't directly use .sum() because it will get a sum total...

can i use a double **for loop**?

what should i do next?

it seems that i am very close to the answer but this is kind of ugent...

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: Do you mean you want to sum each column? Use the `axis` argument, and please try reading [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `array` with shape `(N,M)`:

- use `array.sum(axis=0)` to sum all values in the same column, obtaining an array with shape `(M,)`;
- use `array.sum(axis=1)` to sum all values in the same row, obtaining an array with shape `(N,)`;

See the Numpy documentation for other details:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html